# Python externalise database model file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I'm building a web API in Python flask.

... which needs library SQLAlchemy for db connectivity

... which needs marshmallow to render database results as JSON

Working through a number of examples I now have this code in my app.py file which returns a JSON representation of the table successfully.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError, pre_load
from flask import jsonify
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mssql+pyodbc://localhost/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

### MODELS ###
class Table1(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'MySchema'}
    MyId=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Field1=db.Column(db.Integer)
    Field2=db.Column(db.Integer)

### Schemas ###
class Table1Schema(Schema):
    MyId=fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    Field1=fields.Integer()
    Field2=fields.Integer()

Table1_schema=Table1Schema(many=True)

#### ROUTES ####

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index'

@app.route('/Table2')
def Table2():
    rows=Table1.query.all()
    return jsonify(Table1_schema.dump(rows))
```

Between *MODELS* and *ROUTES* I have a LOT of model code

I want to put this model code in a seperate file but I'm not sure how to split it.

I tried moving all of that model code into it's own file and importing after I define `db` but it doesn't see `db`.

> NameError: name 'db' is not defined

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError, pre_load
from flask import jsonify
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mssql+pyodbc://localhost/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

import mymodelfile
```

How is this kind of thing normally split? Can I just define my models and schemas with a dummy class? I also tried recoding like this sample https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html but after a lot of rewrite I get this

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_autoflush'

There seems to be a lot of different ways to go about the well trodden path of defining database models. Maybe there is an easier way?

The short question is: has anyone used flask+sqlalchemy to make an API? (maybe marshmallow is not required) How did you split your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get this working. I was actually almost there but I got completely sidetracked by `Base = declarative_base()`

This gave me some clues that I needed

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/

I have to say I'm suprised that flask+sqlalchemy still doesn't have a simple way to return a table as JSON. It took a lot of research into dusty corners to work out how to build a database API that returns JSON

If anyone knows an easier way to get SQLAlchemy (or another library) to easily return JSON, I'm all ears.

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
import pyodbc
# This is my external model file
import dbmodel

# set up flask app and sqlalchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mssql+pyodbc://MySQLServerHost/MySQLServerDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

# This is the actual flask code that defines the route and returns the data as JSON
@app.route('/MyTable')
def MyTable():
    rows=dbmodel.MyTable.query.all()
    return jsonify(dbmodel.mytable_schema.dump(rows))
```

## dbmodel.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError, pre_load
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

# https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/

db=SQLAlchemy()

# SQLAlchemy Models
class MyTable(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'MyDBSchema'}
    Col1=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Col2=db.Column(db.Integer)
    Col3=db.Column(db.Integer)

# marshmallow schema
# Seems like marshmallow is the easiest way to create a json response from SQLAlchemy
class MyTableSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model=MyTable


# last piece of the puzzle to use marshmallow
mytable_schema=MyTableSchema(many=True)
```